# Cómo crear múltiples gráficas a partir de un DataFrame - Crosstab en una sola ventana?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Requiero construir múltiples gráficos de un `DataFrame` en una misma ventana. Un ejemplo resumido de mi `DataFrame` general es el siguiente:

```
            codigo sexo  ciclo
0           1      M     11
1           2      F      5
2           3      M     11
3           2      F     10
4           4      F      8
5           1      F     11
6           0      F      9
7           0      F      2
8           0      F      8
9           0      M      5
```

Los múltiples gráficos son la frecuencia normalizada de los códigos por genero y ciclo

Para obtener las frecuencias normalizadas y el gráfico, primero yo cree un `DataFrame` para mujeres y otro para hombre, luego usando `crosstab` calcule la frecuencia normalizada y eso lo gráfico de manera independiente. A continuación muestro el código para mujeres:

```
f= df[df['sexo']=='F']
f_normal = pd.crosstab(f.codigo,f.ciclo,normalize='columns')
f_normal.plot( style= 'o', stacked=True)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Probabilidad')
plt.legend(title='ciclo',fontsize='small' )
plt.title('Mujeres')
plt.show()
```

Ahora tengo las gráficas independientes, lo que necesito es  que las gráficas de mujer y hombre queden en una misma gráfica. El resultado que deseo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente usar el subplots con la siguiente instrucción pero me salio vacío

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax1 = f.plot( style= 'o', stacked=True)
ax2 = m.plot( style= 'o', stacked=True)
```

Estoy aprendiendo hacer gráficos, agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu idea es buena realmente, solo te falta pasar el eje destinado a cada gráfica a [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot) mediante el argumento `ax`.

Un ejemplo reproducible incluyendo el resto de la configuración:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"codigo": (1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "sexo": ("M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M"),
        "ciclo": (11, 5, 11, 10, 8, 11, 9, 2, 8, 5)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

f = df[df['sexo'] == 'F']
f_normal = pd.crosstab(f.codigo, f.ciclo, normalize='columns')
m = df[df['sexo'] == 'M']
m_normal = pd.crosstab(m.codigo, m.ciclo, normalize='columns')

def set_xmargin(axis, margin):
    min_lim, max_lim = axis.get_xlim()
    rang = (max_lim - min_lim) * margin
    axis.set_xlim(min_lim - rang, max_lim + rang)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15,5))

f_normal.plot(ax=ax1, title='Mujeres', style='o', logy=True, stacked=True)
ax1.set_ylabel('Probabilidad de ocurrencia')
ax1.legend(title='ciclo', fontsize='small' )

m_normal.plot(ax=ax2, title="Hombres", style='o', logy=True, stacked=True)
ax2.set_ylabel('Probabilidad de ocurrencia')
ax2.legend(title='ciclo', fontsize='small' )

set_xmargin(ax1, 0.05)
set_xmargin(ax2, 0.05)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Parece ser que hay algunos problemas con el margen en el eje `x` con `pandas.DataFrame.plot` en algunos casos, el problema es que ignora `axis.margins`/`axis.set_xmargin`. De cualquier forma, es bastante simple emularlo, de eso se encarga la función `set_xmargin`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que necesito. Una pregunta cómo se hace para dejar un mayor espacio entre las dos gráficas que quedan en la misma ventana?

Comment: Muchas gracias!